# Smallest ball containing the intersection of a family of balls

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space (see below for the more specific case that I believe should be easier to say something about). Let $B(u, R) = \{x \in X : d(u, x) \leq R\}$, i.e., a closed ball of radius $R$ in this metric space.

Given a family $\{B(u_i, R_i)\}$ of balls, what can we say about the smallest ball containing the intersection of the balls in the 
family? What is the smallest possible radius? How does the 
smallest possible radius change as a function of the center of the 
ball enclosing the intersection? What is the choice of center 
that minimizes the radius? Is it possible to give explicit characterizations (formulae) for each of these questions?

**UPDATE:** I think I was perhaps a bit too vague and too general in my original post. Instead, let's assume $X = \mathbf{R}^n$, and that we have 
the usual norm $\|x\| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$. In this case, we can use (perhaps) the convexity of the norm to aide us. In particular, we are looking for answers (explicit formulae if possible) to the following questions:

(1) What is $g: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$,
$$
g(c) = \inf \{R \in \mathbf{R} : \cap_{i} B(u_i, R_i)  \subseteq B(c, R) \},
$$

(2) Correspondingly, what is the minimal radius?
$$R^\star = \inf_{c \in \mathbf{R}^n} g(c)$$

(3) What choice of $c$ attains the infimal radius above?

As I mention above, it is already interesting to consider the case when we have two balls (i.e., $i = 1, 2$).

Comment: A related question: Is there an efficient way to tell the if intersection of these balls is non-empty?

Answer (score 2):

Even though this doesn't answer any of your questions,
it might help to look at the literature on *the Kneser–Poulsen conjecture*:
If a finite set of balls is repositioned so that the distance between the centers of every pair of balls decreases, then the volume of the intersection increases.
Csikós proved the conjecture for smooth motions (rather than "repositionings"),
and derives some formulas that might be useful to you.

> Gordon, Yehoram, and Mathieu Meyer. "[On the volume of unions and intersections of balls in Euclidean space](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-9090-8_9)." *Geometric Aspects of Functional Analysis*. Birkhäuser Basel, 1995. 91-101.
>
> Bezdek, Károly, and Robert Connelly. "[The Kneser–Poulsen conjecture for spherical polytopes](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-004-0831-1)." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 32.1 (2004): 101-106. [preprint](http://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Econnelly/pkneser.pdf)
>
> Bezdek, Karoly. "[From the Kneser–Poulsen conjecture to ball-polyhedra](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2008.01.011)." *European Journal of Combinatorics* 29.8 (2008): 1820-1830. [arxiv: 0903.4846](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4846)